# AWS DMS Terraform Module Not Picking Up Kinesis Settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-dms, dms

### Description

I'm hitting

```
│ Error: 1 error occurred:
│       * kinesis_settings must be set when engine_name = "kinesis"
│
│
│
│   with module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this["rates_kinesis_target"],
│   on .terraform/modules/replicate_oltp/main.tf line 160, in resource "aws_dms_endpoint" "this":
│  160: resource "aws_dms_endpoint" "this" {
```

I'm trying to figure out why the terraform-aws-dms isn't picking up my `kinesis_settings` variable. Hell, I'm trying to understand how Terraform even understands how to even be able to see what the contexts / structure of the `aws_dms_endpoint` that's dynamically produced in the plan step from the AWS DMS module is at this point.

### Versions

#### DMS Module version [Required]:

1.5.1

#### Terraform version:

```
terraform -version
Terraform v1.1.9
on linux_amd64
```

#### Provider version(s):

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random]
├── module.defaults
│   ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
│   └── provider[terraform.io/builtin/terraform]
├── module.dms_write_to_rating_data_sync_policy
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] >= 3.35.0
├── module.postgres_dms_instance_access
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] >= 3.0.0
└── module.replicate_oltp
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] >= 4.6.0
```

### Reproduction Code [Required]

```
  endpoints = {
    rates_kinesis_target = {
      endpoint_id   = "${local.name}-rates-kinesis-target"
      endpoint_type = "target"
      engine_name   = "kinesis"

      kinesis_settings = {
        # These options are described in
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kinesis.html
        service_access_role_arn        = aws_iam_role.dms_write_to_rating_data_sync.arn
        stream_arn                     = data.aws_kinesis_stream.rating_replication_stream.arn
        partition_include_schema_table = true
        include_partition_value        = true
      }
    }
```

#### Are you using workspaces?:

Yes

#### Have you cleared the local cache (see Notice section above)?:

Yes

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
Terraform init -backend-config=envs/dev-main/backend.tf
Terraform plan
```

### Expected behavior

Terraform should be able to find the `kinesis_settings` as described in the documentation.

## Full TF File

```
resource "random_integer" "rates_mapping_rule_id" {
  min = 1
  max = 500000
}
module "replicate_oltp" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/dms/aws"
  # Question: Why is a brand new module using an old version of a library?
  # Answer: Shippo-tf-services has an AWS module (according to @shippo-eric)
  #         that can't use the latest AWS provider version. Therefore, we need
  #         to use this out of date dms module version.
  version = "1.5.1"

  # "normal" is in comparison to peak season for this instances description and
  # purpose
  repl_subnet_group_name        = "${local.name}-normal-season-replication"
  repl_subnet_group_description = "The Shippo default VPC for ${var.env_name}"
  repl_subnet_group_subnet_ids  = aws_db_subnet_group.oltp_primary.subnet_ids

  # Instance
  repl_instance_allocated_storage            = 20
  repl_instance_auto_minor_version_upgrade   = true
  repl_instance_allow_major_version_upgrade  = true
  repl_instance_apply_immediately            = true
  repl_instance_engine_version               = "3.4.6"
  repl_instance_multi_az                     = false
  repl_instance_preferred_maintenance_window = "sun:10:30-sun:14:30"
  repl_instance_publicly_accessible          = false
  repl_instance_class                        = "dms.t3.medium"
  repl_instance_id                           = "${var.env_name}-normal-season-replication"
  repl_instance_vpc_security_group_ids       = [module.postgres_dms_instance_access.security_group_id]
  # This saves us from `EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name dms-cloudwatch-logs-role already exists.`
  # errors on three potential IAM roles shared between many services. These roles
  # were created in 2019 in dev-main, and dev-qa, and prod-data but have not
  # been confirmed in prod.
  create_iam_roles = false

  endpoints = {
    rates_kinesis_target = {
      endpoint_id   = "${local.name}-rates-kinesis-target"
      endpoint_type = "target"
      engine_name   = "kinesis"

      kinesis_settings = {
        service_access_role_arn        = aws_iam_role.dms_write_to_rating_data_sync.arn
        stream_arn                     = data.aws_kinesis_stream.rating_replication_stream.arn
        partition_include_schema_table = true
        include_partition_value        = true
      }
    }

    postgresql_source = {
      database_name               = var.source_db_name
      endpoint_id                 = "${local.name}-postgresql-source"
      extra_connection_attributes = "heartbeatFrequency=1;"
      endpoint_type               = "source"
      engine_name                 = "aurora-postgresql"
      port                        = 5432
      username                    = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.replication_user.secret_string)["login"]
      password                    = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.replication_user.secret_string)["password"]
      server_name                 = data.aws_rds_cluster.oltp.endpoint
      # TODO: Setting this to None but we should test this with `require` to see if we need
      # a root CA cert or not.
      ssl_mode = "none"
    }
  }

  replication_tasks = {
    cdc_postgresql_to_kinesis = {
      replication_task_id       = "${local.name}-postgresql-cdc-to-kinesis-for-rates"
      migration_type            = "cdc"
      replication_task_settings = file("${path.cwd}/task-templates/default_cdc_settings.json")
      table_mappings = templatefile("${path.cwd}/task-templates/api_shipment_rate_query_table_mapping.tmpl",
        { tables_to_replicate = [{
          rule_id   = random_integer.rates_mapping_rule_id.id,
          rule_name = "replicate_api_shipment_rate_query",
      target_table = "api_shipmentratequery" }] })
      source_endpoint_key = "postgresql_source"
      target_endpoint_key = "rates_kinesis_target"
    }
  }
}
```

## Relevant terraform-aws-dms Module Code

At a fundamental level I don't get how the `engine_type` and `engine_name` are associated with the dynamic block in this module.

I also don't understand why the dynamic block has a list of objects? That makes it look like this module supports multiple kinesis_settings arguments?

```
resource "aws_dms_endpoint" "this" {
  for_each = { for k, v in var.endpoints : k => v if var.create }

  certificate_arn             = try(aws_dms_certificate.this[each.value.certificate_key].certificate_arn, null)
  database_name               = lookup(each.value, "database_name", null)
  endpoint_id                 = each.value.endpoint_id
  endpoint_type               = each.value.endpoint_type
  engine_name                 = each.value.engine_name
  extra_connection_attributes = lookup(each.value, "extra_connection_attributes", null)
  kms_key_arn                 = lookup(each.value, "kms_key_arn", null)
  password                    = lookup(each.value, "password", null)
  port                        = lookup(each.value, "port", null)
  server_name                 = lookup(each.value, "server_name", null)
  service_access_role         = lookup(each.value, "service_access_role", null)
  ssl_mode                    = lookup(each.value, "ssl_mode", null)
  username                    = lookup(each.value, "username", null)

# Skipping elastisearch and kafka settings
  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kinesis.html
  dynamic "kinesis_settings" {
    for_each = try([each.value.kinesis_settings], [])
    content {
      include_control_details        = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "include_control_details", null)
      include_null_and_empty         = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "include_null_and_empty", null)
      include_partition_value        = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "include_partition_value", null)
      include_table_alter_operations = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "include_table_alter_operations", null)
      include_transaction_details    = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "include_transaction_details", null)
      message_format                 = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "message_format", null)
      partition_include_schema_table = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "partition_include_schema_table", null)
      service_access_role_arn        = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "service_access_role_arn", null)
      stream_arn                     = lookup(kinesis_settings.value, "stream_arn", null)
    }
  }
```

## Trace Log

```
2022-06-22T23:50:40.484Z [WARN]  Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" produced an invalid plan for module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this["postgresql_source"], but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
    The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
      - .tags: planned value cty.NullVal(cty.Map(cty.String)) does not match config value cty.MapValEmpty(cty.String)
      - .redshift_settings: attribute representing nested block must not be unknown itself; set nested attribute values to unknown instead
2022-06-22T23:50:40.485Z [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState to workingState for module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this["postgresql_source"]
2022-06-22T23:50:40.485Z [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState: writing state object for module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this["postgresql_source"]
2022-06-22T23:50:40.485Z [ERROR] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this[\"rates_kinesis_target\"]" error: 1 error occurred:
        * kinesis_settings must be set when engine_name = "kinesis"
2022-06-22T23:50:40.485Z [TRACE] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this[\"rates_kinesis_target\"]": visit complete, with errors
2022-06-22T23:50:40.485Z [TRACE] writeChange: recorded Create change for module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this["postgresql_source"]
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this[\"postgresql_source\"]": visit complete
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.485Z [TRACE] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.19.0_x5: Served request: @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.9.1/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:791 @module=sdk.proto tf_proto_version=5.2 tf_provider_addr=provider tf_resource_type=aws_dms_endpoint tf_req_id=4fa6f44f-c38e-fbf5-37af-3b50cbc67640 tf_rpc=PlanResourceChange timesta
mp=2022-06-22T23:50:40.485Z
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this": dynamic subgraph encountered errors: 1 error occurred:
        * kinesis_settings must be set when engine_name = "kinesis"
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [ERROR] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this" error: 1 error occurred:
        * kinesis_settings must be set when engine_name = "kinesis"
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this": visit complete, with errors
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this (expand)": dynamic subgraph encountered errors: 1 error occurred:
        * kinesis_settings must be set when engine_name = "kinesis"
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [ERROR] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this (expand)" error: 1 error occurred:
        * kinesis_settings must be set when engine_name = "kinesis"
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] vertex "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this (expand)": visit complete, with errors
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.replicate_oltp.output.endpoints (expand)" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_replication_task.this (expand)" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.replicate_oltp.output.replication_tasks (expand)" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_event_subscription.this (expand)" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.replicate_oltp.output.event_subscriptions (expand)" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.replicate_oltp (close)" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping
2022-06-22T23:50:40.486Z [INFO]  backend/local: plan operation completed
╷
│ Error: 1 error occurred:
│       * kinesis_settings must be set when engine_name = "kinesis"
│
│
│
│   with module.replicate_oltp.aws_dms_endpoint.this["rates_kinesis_target"],
│   on .terraform/modules/replicate_oltp/main.tf line 160, in resource "aws_dms_endpoint" "this":
│  160: resource "aws_dms_endpoint" "this" {
```

## Edit

After some further digging this settings declaration gets terraform plan to work

```
      kinesis_settings = {
        #  service_access_role_arn        = aws_iam_role.dms_write_to_rating_data_sync.arn
        stream_arn                     = data.aws_kinesis_stream.rating_replication_stream.arn
        partition_include_schema_table = true
        include_partition_value        = true
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging yesterday a co-worker and I found a modification that built a plan correctly

```
      kinesis_settings = {
        #  service_access_role_arn        = aws_iam_role.dms_write_to_rating_data_sync.arn
        stream_arn                     = data.aws_kinesis_stream.rating_replication_stream.arn
        partition_include_schema_table = true
        include_partition_value        = true
      }
```

Which lead to this github ticket https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30937

and finally lead to this terraform setup

```
      kinesis_settings = {
        service_access_role_arn        = "arn:aws:iam::${module.defaults.aws_account_id}:role/${var.env_name}-dms-assume-kinesis-write-role
        stream_arn                     = data.aws_kinesis_stream.rating_replication_stream.arn
        partition_include_schema_table = true
        include_partition_value        = true
      }
```